# How could Tony Stark make this in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony is able to make

> his own Infinity Gauntlet

how was he able to as, in *Avengers: Infinity War*

> Thanos went all the way to Nidavellir to get his, and needed dwarves and magic to build his

How was Tony able to build this using only human technology?

Comment: And I've done it, like a moth to flame, knowing I could never go back, I have moused over the spoilers and ruined the movie for myself. I leave this here only as a warning to others.

Comment: @Sidney There are more important things to be spoiled honestly (by which I mean you can still really enjoy the film)... but for those that haven't moused over yet, still don't!

Comment: At the start of the movie, they get the original Gauntlet, albeit with a few gaps. Presumably they didn’t just leave it next to Thanos’s corpse, so he had something to start from.

Comment: Related: [How did Tony Stark create this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99799/49)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/210937/931 This one's correct answer. Tony reverse-engineered the original Gauntlet which Avengers obtained after killing Thanos in the beginning.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Tony has spent quite some time studying two Infinity Stones in *Avengers* and *Age of Ultron*, so he already has some familiarity with them.

In addition, a day or two previously he invented a wrist-sized device that enables successful time travel in his spare hours between lunch and his young daughter finally going to bed. He's a smart guy.

As Thor explains to MCU lynchpin Jane Foster in his first movie, magic is just sufficiently-advanced science. Tony, presumably with Bruce and Rocket's help, figured out how to make an Infinity Gauntlet from first principles.

Comment: I liked the bit about "sufficiently advanced science".

Comment: @Stark07 totally my thing. Arthur C. Clarke ripped me off.

Comment: Foster as MCU lynchpin?

Comment: I wouldn't mind an explanation of how he made a time machine in a day.  Something about an inverted mobius strip and then he suddenly manufactured a dozen wristwatch-sized time machines?

Comment: Stark may have worked out the theory overnight, but it’s not at all clear that the machine was built in a day...

Comment: Bruce made the machine that sends people through the quantum realm, and it took more than a day, and was based on data from many years of Pym's research. Pym had already built a machine that could send people into the quantum realm in the Ant-Man/Wasp film. The part that Tony did in a day was working out how to make the component that enables the user to navigate the quantum realm correctly (so they don't get lost or turn into babies and geriatrics).

Comment: Stark now has full glory access to nano-tech.  His new armour sprouts whatever extras he wants at a whim.  The blueprints he works out in simulation would be sent straight to the nano-bot "factory floor".  Think "3-D printing", only several orders cooler.

Comment: My interpretation was that Tony took far more than a day to get the time machine working. From the way he was acting it seemed like he had been trying (and failing with) different simulations for many nights before the one shown on screen.

Comment: @MartianInvader: yeah, could be.

Comment: There's also the fact that Tony and Bruce were the two smartest people on MCU Earth at the time (other contenders Shuri and Hank Pym were snapped), and they had Rocket's help. Spitballing a bit more, Eitri could have told Rocket and Thor about how the Gauntlet works while they were on Nidavellir in IW, or one of those two could have contacted Eitri for help (assuming he wasn't snapped). Plus, Thanos' Gauntlet let him use the stones to his will in various ways and combinations, while the Stark Gauntlet may have been able to Snap and un-Snap and nothing else.

Comment: @MartianInvader Step 1: Spent 30 years inventing time machine.  Step 2:  Use time machine to sneak blueprints onto your sleep-deprived past-self's computer within 24 hours of him starting to invent a time machine.  Step 3: ???  Step 4: Profit

Answer (score 31):

There's no indication that Thanos needed Dwarven magic and the forge at Nidavellir to create an Infinity Gauntlet that works. What he actually needed was the knowledge that the dwarves possessed.

> **Thor:** Eitri, this isn't about your hands. Every weapon you've designed, every axe, hammer, sword...It's all inside your head. Now I know all hope feels lost. Trust me, I know. But together, you and I, we can kill Thanos.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Tony possesses the same knowledge to create an Infinity Gauntlet because he has spent time studying the Infinity Stones to quite a complex level. He has studied the Mind Stone and the Space Stone over the course of the movies.

He also has the help of Dr. Hulk who has previously studied the Infinity Stones with Tony and Rocket who is incredibly intelligent and has come into contact with the Stones before even wielding the Power Stone with the Guardians of the Galaxy.

Answer (score 19):

By this point in the movie, they would have had the original available to reverse engineer.

> While Thanos destroyed the Infinity stones he did not destroy the gauntlet. Presumably, Stark recovered it after Thor killed Thanos.

Collectively, the Avengers Engineering team all had experience with the Infinity stones
(Tony, Bruce, Rocket, Nebula)

It's even likely that Nebula may have known how the original was made.

oh and don't forget that "magic is just sufficiently-advanced science"

Comment: +1.  You make a point that doesn't seem to have been made in any other answers, and it's a very salient one.  Even if the object was (heavily) damaged, it could still provide significant insights.  It would be a little better if the acquisition of the item in question was more explicitly shown, but it's plausible.

Answer (score 15):

Let's see. He did have a couple of resources at his disposal. Mainly,

- Rocket and his knowledge of weaponry. As we have seen, Rocket is also a very talented engineer.
- Thor and his knowledge of Asgardian/cosmic tech. We have seen in Thor 1 and 2 that he does have some degree of understanding of Asgardian/cosmic tech.

We're talking about the guy who did build the equivalent of the Asgardian destroyer (minus the indestructible metal and face-beam), without any magic involved.

Comment: And Rocket’s right there alongside Tony and Professor Hulk when they’re putting the stones into the Iron Gauntlet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Indeed he is!

Comment: Well Thor wasn't in his better state to remember anything about Asgardien/cosmic tech :D

Comment: @DhonJoe The big Thor-owski :D

Comment: God of Thunderthighs

Answer (score 5):

As others have said... he's had time to study the stones.. but, more importantly, things that HOUSE the stones.

He's been able to study the cube that contains a stone
He's been able to study the "glow stick of destiny" (Loki's staff) that holds a stone
He was probably studying Vision to see how he could hold a stone in his head

While Tony used to be an engineer, in the latest movies they've been showing him as a Data Scientist. He's created neural nets / AI's that grind though vast amounts of machine learning / deep learning. The way this works is you set up inputs, nodes and an output / goal. The nodes (could be thousands.. millions) are all decision points. Then you fire off the inputs (what you know about the stones, what they've been in, how they react to things.. eg: some stones seem ok to hold by hand by a human, like the soul stone, while others consume the user unless they're sufficiently powerful enough) you send all that through the machine learning / deep learning algorithms and then yuo.. wait... until it spits out an answer that best matches your goal.

The trick with machine learning / deep learning algorithms is that they're shooting for statistical probabilities. You want models that are 100% accurate. But, sometimes you only get 90% or less.. predicitive modelling, etc. (eg: in data sci they had us run genetics from known cancer patients and mash up against unknown patients. You create a training data used to train your model, and a test data set to test it to see how accurate it is. For really complex stuff, you're going to be at less then 100% accuracy / prediction.)

> Tony gets baked at the end of the movie, which means his gauntlet was flawed.. it worked to do the task, but didn't protect him from the blowback of power. But, it protected him amazingly well seeing as how it let a mere human use all 6 tones to accomplish greatness and still be alive after-the-fact to live long enough to know they won. He was there and saw how Thanos got burned from the backlash of the gauntlet. So, he probably knew that he had to factor in the power of the stones. But, when time is a factor, you can only run so many models for so long before you have to go "you know what, it's not 100% fool-proof, but it's the best we got." If he had more time, he might have been able to make a guantlet that surpassed even the Dwarves. But, with limited technology and limited time.. he did the best he could with what he had. And, it was enough to enable a human being to weild all 6 stones and snap his fingers. It killed him, but that's still ludicriously impressive... seeing as how the power stone alone almost fried Quill in the first Guardians movie.. and he was half-cosmic.

tl;dr ... Tony is the ultimate geek in these movies, from engineer to data scientist, and he's got AI's and deep learning at his disposal.

If we can (in real life) have IBM's Watson beating the pants off of contestants on Jeopardy, then imagine the kind of AI tech a super-rich tech genius super-hero guy must have to help him invent toys.

Answer (score 2):

One point that the other answers don't cover is the fact that the point of Thanos' gauntlet wasn't just to "harness" the stones -- if nothing else, the first Guardians of the Galaxy movie shows that a big hammer can do the trick in a pinch -- but also to *survive using them*.

If you compare the amount of side effects and sheer damage inflicted on the wielder of the Infinity Gauntlet compared to the one Tony bashed together in his lab, you'll note that the  latter caused *significantly* more bleedover, even to Thanos.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that since Thanos's gauntlet also blew out when he snapped.  It performed just fine when he used fewer than all six stones, and we never got an opportunity to see how Tony's gauntlet performed at those "lower" capacities since they never attempted it—it was constructed _solely_ for a snap attempt, so limiting ourselves to that context the two performed more or less the same way.

Comment: This was my understanding as well. Anything can theoretically "wield" the stones. What the infinity gauntlet did was provide some safety to not destroy whomever wields it (Hulk and Thanos are special cases). Also it was never shown that Iron Mans gauntlet could actually use the stones individually ala infinity gauntlet... Thanos pulled the power stone out to use it individually (but one could argue that was done due to circumstance of fighting Captain Marvel specifically).

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with all the statements RE Tony only needing the knowledge to create one.

If he did, then you're all saying he has the power to create hundreds of Stormbreakers and Mjolnir. Thanos went through the trouble to Nidavellir to create the Infinity Gauntlet because of - the materials used, the dying star used, and the profession of the Dwarves, otherwise he could've gone anywhere else (quote from Rocket to Stark "you're only a genius on Earth").

And let's clear something up. The problem here isn't making something that can 'hold' all the stones together, it's making a device that could 'harness' (i.e, make use of) these stones.

So I think the only possible explanation here, is if they took Thanos' gauntlet and Tony reverse-engineered it to create it. But even this I dislike, as it wasn't even shown in the movie that the team took it with them.

Comment: Surely, if he reverse engineered the gauntlet, he had the "knowledge to create one"?

Comment: Tony had already been able to see and research the "actual" gauntlet ahead of time as has been stated in other answers, as well as the cube and scepter that housed other infinity gems. With the research he had available to him it may have opened the possibility for him to more easily create his own. Even still, just because he was able to create his own that is not the same as creating an item that has access to the "bifrost," aka connecting to an einstein-rosen bridge. Tony is smart, and we know he makes mistakes in his research, but it would presumably take more effort for a first creation.

Comment: RE Knowledge - what I meant was that I disagreed that he already had the knowledge to build one, or built one without the reverse engineering of the original gauntlet. But even with this theory, I disagree. Because I don't think it's just 'knowledge' you require to create one.

Comment: I don't know why you brought up bifrost...it only applies to the Stormbreaker. If anything, that just proves right with what I'm saying; about how these things are only forged by Dwarves and at Nivadellir.

I think it's poor form to say that he had already been able to see and research ahead of time. He never researched the soul stone, power stone, reality stone or time stone. He never actually researched the space stone either. The only stone he had anything to do with, is the mind stone.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that everyone is forgetting - by this point in the movie he has already done it once, and in a way that can change size to fit whomever puts it on.

Given that, he's probably used something similar to what his current suit is made out of, so the "how" is already part of what he's wearing given how he controls it via the implants he added several movies ago.

The original "how" he could do it for the first one, see the other answers :-)

(Answer deliberately vague so no need for spoiler tags - several other answers could definitely do with them though...)